# What is the maximum amount of cells you can set when using Excel REST API with SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office365-restapi

I'm trying to use the Excel REST API with SharePoint online to set some cell values and to retrieve some calculated fields.

It seems this goes well up until passing 10 cell values. When passing more I get a *503 Service Unavailable* back from the API.

The amount of characters in the URI is less than the approximant supported 2000 characters.

Any limitations on the maximum amount of fields you can set is not described in the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394477.aspx

Example:

[https://business-my.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/personal/john/documents/some.xlsx/model/Ranges('Input_Output!S2|S13')?$format=atom&Ranges('Input_Output!C3')=val1&Ranges('Input_Output!C4')=val2&Ranges('Input_Output!C5')=val3&Ranges('Input_Output!C8')=val4&Ranges('Input_Output!G2')=val5&Ranges('Input_Output!G3')=val6&Ranges('Input_Output!G4')=val7&Ranges('Input_Output!G5')=val8&Ranges('Input_Output!G6')=val9&Ranges('Input_Output!G10')=val10](https://business-my.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/personal/john/documents/some.xlsx/model/Ranges('Input_Output!S2%7CS13')?$format=atom&Ranges('Input_Output!C3')=val1&Ranges('Input_Output!C4')=val2&Ranges('Input_Output!C5')=val3&Ranges('Input_Output!C8')=val4&Ranges('Input_Output!G2')=val5&Ranges('Input_Output!G3')=val6&Ranges('Input_Output!G4')=val7&Ranges('Input_Output!G5')=val8&Ranges('Input_Output!G6')=val9&Ranges('Input_Output!G10')=val10)

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I just now noticed the following in the response header: **X-XLSMsgId:RequestLimitsExceeded** What exactly does it mean? Would it be possible to set mulltiple cells in a range instead of separate query parameters to overcome any limits?

Comment: Doesn't anybody have any clue at all?

Comment: Hi @donerler. Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Given that this API takes in the input data in the URL, the number of input cells is limited. 
Have you looked in to the new EXCEL REST API that is now available as part of Microsoft Graph? This does allow large input cells. 
Check this API:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/range_update.md

http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/range_update

Answer (score 0):

I could only get one cell updated and that was in the download, not in the source document. That would have been fine if I could have counted on the user to save it back. This is not guaranteed. I am not the ultimate or penultimate authority so keep looking.